# HTTPS requests render a duplicate of new site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, dns

Our company rebranded recently and so migrated from a site i.e xyz.com to xyz.co.uk.

dns settings have been updated to point the domain name to the new server.

The site redirects as expected using HTTP, but doesn't redirect for HTTPS traffic. The website is rendered as an exact duplicate of the new xyz.co.uk domain and is causing SEO issues as it is indexed within Google.

The old domain doesn't have an SSL cert, the new one does The site is hosted on WordPress CMS on pantheon.io, the dns settings are with media temple.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You dont have a SSL cert for `example.com` yet `https://example.com` is showing the site?

Comment: @DusanBajic - The site we moved from no longer has an SSL certificate. The new site does.

Comment: I see, but what happens now if you try `https://oldsite.com` in browser?

Comment: it gives a message saying this site isn't trusted. If you ignore the message it takes you to https oldsite.com but the content is for https newsite.com

Comment: Then it looks like `.htaccess` file that should do the redirect is not configured correctly, can you share its content?